# Is there a way to alias a longwinded generic type in the scope of a class?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a shared repository class using a shared entity/document type, that looks kind of like this:

```
type IEntity<TData extends {}, TType extends string = string> = TData & {
    id: string;
    type: TType;
    createdAtIso: string;
}

class Repository<TData extends {}, TType extends string = string> {
    constructor(private _type: TType) { }

    save(data: TData): IEntity<TData, TType> {
        return this._save({
            id: 'asdf',
            type: this._type,
            createdAtIso: new Date().toISOString(),
            ...data
        });
    }

    _save(entity: IEntity<TData, TType>): IEntity<TData, TType> {
        // save entity here
        return entity;
    }
}
```

The point is to encapsulate the book-keeping in TEntity, and have the code using the repo only have to care about what it specifically wants to store.

That said, this means the construct `IEntity<TData, TType>` is repeated a zillion times within the repository class. At module toplevel, I could use a `type` alias to create a shorter name for the type; is there any construct I could use to alias a type within a class declaration, using the generic type arguments it takes?

Comment: You could a type parameter as an sort of type alias, but that would have limiting consequences. There was a discussion to allow type aliases in classes but that seems to have gone nowhere https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7061

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - sadly that's not very useful near as I can tell; TS (correctly) assumes that the argument may be any arbitrary subtype of the parameter constraint, i.e. may have additional required properties, so you can't meaningfully return an instance of the subtype.

Comment: Yes, it is not a good solution that is why I did not post it as an answer. Don't think we can do better right now though.