# Is there a type-safe way to filter out instances of a given variant from a list of objects of a discriminated union type?

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of type families that involve mostly shared properties, with each "subtype" adding maybe one or two properties. (Say you're ordering food online, an order item for a pizza lets you add ingredients, other items don't.)

Most of the code doesn't care to distinguish these and just passes the values through, but for presentation I need to handle the subtypes separately.

So I want a function that lets me pluck items of a given variant from an array of objects of the union type. The closest I got is:

```
type ThingVariant = "foo" | "bar";

interface IThingBase<TVariant extends ThingVariant> {
    variant: TVariant;
}

interface IFoo extends IThingBase<'foo'> {
    foo: number;
}

interface IBar extends IThingBase<'bar'> {
    bar: number;
}

type Thing = IFoo | IBar;

const things: Thing[] = [
    { variant: 'foo', foo: 1 },
    { variant: 'bar', bar: 2 },
    { variant: 'foo', foo: 1 },
    { variant: 'bar', bar: 2 },
]

function getThingsOfVariant<TVariant extends ThingVariant,
    TThing extends IThingBase<TVariant>&Thing>(variant: TVariant): TThing[] {
    return things.filter((it): it is TThing => it.variant === variant);
}

function getFoos(): IFoo[] {
    return getThingsOfVariant<'foo', IFoo>('foo');
}
```

My problem with the above code is that `getThingsOfVariant<'foo', IFoo>('foo')` is a rather redundant mouthful. Especially considering TypeScript can handle this type narrowing automatically when using `if` or `switch` over a discriminator. Another annoyance is that because of the explicit type guard signature on the predicate to `filter()`, that part itself bypasses type-checking; i.e. returning `true` from it would be legal but incorrect.

Is there a way to implement this sort of thing "cleanly", actually leveraging the type checker and ideally type inference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the call to `getThingsOfVariant` better using `Extract` to get the type from the union:

```
function getThingsOfVariant<TVariant extends Thing['variant']>(variant: TVariant): Extract<Thing, IThingBase<TVariant>>[] {
    return things.filter((it): it is Extract<Thing, IThingBase<TVariant>> => it.variant === variant);
}

function getFoos(): IFoo[] {
    return getThingsOfVariant('foo');
}
```

The type guard will still need to be a manual error prone affair unfortunately.

Comment: this already helps loads since with inference it's now legal in Angular templates without a wrapper function, yay

Comment: I need to see if I can abuse Extract elsewhere in my codebase, I think I have a bunch of constructs like this with pairs of similarly related type parameters. (Might have posted a question about them recently too; where this would address the problem I was having from another angle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233473/is-there-a-way-to-alias-a-longwinded-generic-type-in-the-scope-of-a-class?noredirect=1#comment97202830_55233473 - I'll have to see if it helps when I revisit that code.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Thing = { variant: 'foo', foo: number } | { variant: 'bar', bar: number };

const things: Thing[] = [
    { variant: 'foo', foo: 1 },
    { variant: 'bar', bar: 2 },
    { variant: 'foo', foo: 1 },
    { variant: 'bar', bar: 2 },
];


const foos = things.flatMap(x => x.variant === "foo" ? [x] : []);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.flatMap()` isn't part of the JS spec yet and TypeScript doesn't have a signature for it so this just makes `foos` of type `any`

Comment: You'll have to enable `esnext`, but it is there: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/eb2297df022f6b1f284aff96e93c06097bb01ea5/lib/lib.esnext.array.d.ts#L147

Comment: Also probably need to couple it with a polyfill like https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/v3.1.3/packages/core-js/modules/es.array.flat-map.js

Comment: hm, I was trying that on the js.org TS playground, guess TS added it too recently